# PHP OOP Design: DB actively conncted

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

In OOP design of the database abstraction layer, is it proper to create a wrapper object for the original DB object that uses it? To supply all the user,pass within itself and create an active connection so that other objects such as CRUD could inherit it and already have an open connection?

<-- EDIT -->

some background: what i'm trying to build here is a good separation between the db-logic and the business-logic
so i thought of creating a table CRUD object to be inherited by other business logic objects
but the problem arises when i thought of how would the connectivity to the DB would transfer
between those objects. it didnt feel so right to just pass it as parameters like

```
class TableCrud(AbstractDb $db) {...}
class BusinessObject(TableCrud $tc) { ... }
```

also another approach that doesnt feel so right to have an object that contains the DB user credentials, within it that open a connectivity and let TableCrud inherit it.

i'm sure that i'm missing some in between object mechanics here.

Comment: It's a little more complex than "yes/no, it is/isn't proper".  Depends completely on your purpose.  What you describe requires a parent static or possibly singleton class to hold the active connection for all spawned objects or child classes.  How many different connections will you have?  How big (in terms of script files) is the site or app?  Do you want the script to be portable to other sites/apps?  Do you foresee switching DB extensions later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I write database models, it typically goes like this:

Model.php:

```
include('connect.php');

class Model{}...
```

connect.php:

```
include('Database.php');
include('dblogin.db');

$db = new Database( $user, ...);
```

Database.php:

```
class Database{}
```

dblogin.db:

```
$user = user;
...etc...
```

`tl;dr`:  Yes, that's how you might add an abstraction layer on top of your DAL.

Comment: hey thanks for your replay but i still havent understand somthing if we stick to your example, class Module() is going to use  the included db connected object ? is it going to get it as one of its parameters ?
cause if so thats a problem i dont want

Comment: @Xeus, thanks for the accept.  To answer your question, no.  Each function in `Model` or your case `Module` that needs database access uses the previously defined $db variable (set up in `connect.php`) by referencing it like: `global $db;` at the beginning of the function.  It's not the prettiest, but it's the best solution I've found so far.